# how to trim the SSD disk of an hybrid Linux soft RAID?

Tags: ssd, raid, mdadm

We are considering implementing an Hybrid Linux Raid with SSD+HD by using the "writemostly" flag that supposedly makes the raid write further to the HD than to SSD while maintaining the benefits of read speeds. Due to the use of OpenVZ our kernel is still on late 2.6.32 versions
Our concern is that we have not found a clear info about the fstrim solutions on this settings as fstrim and a python script called mdtrim are thought for filesystems that in our case contains one of each.

So the question is:
- would fstrim harmless to the HD drive "part" of the raid on this setting?
- how can I make the trim process over "only" the SSD part of the raid?